# Using Verilog to implement light control

Tags: verilog, fpga

This is my main code. The function is switching the light on or off when I toggle.
Maybe the t filp-flop can help?

```
module demo(
input switch1,switch2,
output reg light=1'b0
);

    always@(switch1 or switch2)
    begin
    light <= ~light;
    end
    
endmodule
```

And the testbench

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps

module demo_test;

reg switch1,switch2;
wire light;

demo d1(.switch1(switch1),
            .switch2(switch2),
            .light(light));
            
initial
begin: in_set_blk 
    #0 switch1 =1'b0;
        switch2 =1'b0;
        $display ($time, "light=%d \n",light);
    #10 switch1 =1'b1;
        switch2 =1'b0;
        $display ($time, "light=%d \n",light);
    #10 switch1 =1'b0;
        switch2 =1'b0;
        $display ($time, "light=%d \n",light);
    #10 switch1 =1'b0;
        switch2 =1'b1;
        $display ($time, "light=%d \n",light);
    #10 switch1 =1'b0;
        switch2 =1'b0;
        $display ($time, "light=%d \n",light);
    #10 $stop;
    #10 $finish;
end
        
endmodule
```

This is the modelsim waveform diagram; I think it works well:

[image: and this is the modelsim waveform diagram, I think it work well]

This is the diagram in RTL viewer; that is the strange part:

[image: and this is the diagram in RTL viewer, that is the strange part]

Diagram in RTL viewer is so strange; the input even didn't connect to the inverter.

Any error in my main Verilog code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is that your `demo` module Verilog code is not synthesizable.

Not all legal Verilog code is synthesizable.  Synthesis tools recognize specific coding patterns, but your code does not match any of those patterns.  There should be documentation with your FPGA tool set that shows what syntax is supported for synthesis.

This is why your RTL viewer tool gives you a strange diagram.

Here is how the simulation works.  At time=0, you set `light` and the 2 switch inputs to 0.  At time=10, you change `switch1` to 1.  This triggers the `always` block, executing the `light <= ~light;` assignment.  This sets `light=1`.

Every time either of the inputs change, the `always` block is triggered, causing `light` to toggle.

If that is how you want the design to work, you should consider using edge detectors.  However, that requires flip-flops and a clock.

Answer (score 1):

Your code represents an *implied latch*, which is usually not synthesizable. This is a common mistake when you try to use always blocks with sensititivity lists (verilog 95). Your code will simulate correctly, but synthseis requres that all *inputs* of  the always block are listed in the sensitivity list and all elements from the sensitivity list must be inputs to the block (flops excluded).

```
 always@(switch1 or switch2)
    begin
    light <= ~light;
    end
```

In the code above the result is not a function of the *switch1,2* listed in the sensitivity list and sensitivity list does not include *light*.

In your case a flop is needed. `light <= ~light` represents a zero-delay loop if used in combinatorial logic or in a latch. It can only be resolved with a flop.

Flop needs a clock. Clock must be generated in test bench and flagged in synthesis.

The code can look like the following:

```
   always@(posedge clk) begin
      if (switch1 || switch2)
          light <= ~light;
   end
```

Flops are recognized by synthesis tools due to specific programming pattern and do not require listing of all inputs.

As a general suggestion: do not use sensitivity lists for combinatorial logic or latches (flops excluded). Modern verilog (v2k) allows you to use `always @*` construt instead.